# Economical way to prevent dusting from AAC blocks in your garage?

Tags: walls, dust

Two main walls of my garage are made of Autoclaved Aerated Concrete (AAC) blocks and they produce a lot of dusting. Total surface I need to is around 25 square meters.

What can I use to prevent future dusting from the walls? I would prefer something liquid where I can use a roller or a paintbrush instead of preparing the mix with water (as this would involve more dust and efforth).

In case it matters, I live in UK. I seen people recommending PVA but I seen many types and I don't know which type and quantity I need.

I also have concreete floor (15sqm) for which I need a solution, for the same reasons, I don't want more dust in the garage. The garage is used only for storage, so I am not concerned much about traffic. Still, I don't want to see the coating peeling from the walls or ceiling in the next 4-5 years.

Comment: Ok this one is bugging me, don't know why.  First thing I'd like you to do is put plastic sheet along the walls and floor as a test, wherever that won't be too badly in the way.  I want to see if moisture is coming through the walls, so look for condensation accumulating.  That will have a big bearing on whether/how to paint it.

Comment: I have no problems with water infiltratiin, I only want to acoid the dust created by the AAC walls and concrete floor, both of them being a permanent source of dust.

Comment: Yes, your walls will look dry normally, because normally if it comes through it just instantly evaporates.  Hence the plastic sheets (which can be thin stuff), moisture will not come through that, and on cool mornings you'll see condensation on the inside of the plastic sheet, that's the warning sign we are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with this mix:
- 1 part PVA
- 5 parts white masonery paint

I also added some extra water (less than 1 part) to ease mixing and to compensate for the big absortion abilities of the blocks.

I will post some photos after but it was looking promising even after 15 minutes.